# How to add a script tag to the end of a URL which can be covered as a part of XSS Testing

Tags: manual-testing, security-testing

I am trying to test a local website link for a possible XSS attack. Can you please help me looking for a solution in way that if i add some script tag to the end of the URL under test, then it either throw and exception or an alert. For Eg: If link under test is: `https://testmysite/login.aspx` then what kind of script I can append with URL so that it returns an Exception or an Alert. I hope that the question is clear. Pardon me if this has been already asked as I am unable to find the exact problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Joe's resource, the OWASP site has a lot on XSS too: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29

I would also encourage you to look a bit further than OWASP once you get those base concepts down.  There are MANY ways to bypass basic XSS protections.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/

Their example is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('This is an XSS Vulnerability')
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't that more for including in the body of a page? If you want to attack he URL don't you need ones that take parameters, in which case his example won't be susceptible to it?

Comment: I agree. His example doesn't actually lend itself to this vulnerability. But I think his was a made-up example, without an understanding of the issue. Hopefully the link will clear that up.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys and link is worth but when i tried to put my site inside the script then the page stays as it is. For eg. if i am on login page then if i try to append the script then page don't display any alert or exception. Is it fine ? How do we get to know that the page has been attacked ?

Comment: Seems you need do a LOT more reading - the example Joe gave is for a site where part of the page is made up from user input e.g. a comment, if there is an exploit then a msg box will appear. Please read the link Joe gave

Comment: Sure Phil. I'll get back in case of issues. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, I've shared an article on XSS attack and cheat sheet for scripts - http://www.cygnet-infotech.com/is-your-website-safe-against-cross-site-scripting-attacks

Comment: This is not an answer to the question - it's basically spam for your website.